# Logout button navigationController Issue with the navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, logout

I have a login view in my application which loads the main menu view after the user enters the correct username and password. I'm using this to go to main menu view:

```
MenuViewController *menuViewController=[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
        menuViewController.title=@"Felton";
        UINavigationController *tnavController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];
        tnavController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);
        [menuViewController release];
        self.navController=tnavController;
        [navController release];
        for(UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [self.view addSubview:self.navController.view];
```

So my question is how exactly am I going to go back to the login page when the logout button is pressed.  I've tried the same way as above but the problem I have is that each time the user presses the logout button the login page gets 1 navigation bar, and they pile on each other each time.  Is there any way that I can stop this from happening?  Because, my login page shouldn't have a navigation bar.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not clear from your question what the exact flow through your app is, you certainly shouldn't be adding the navController view as a subview.

You'd be better placed to have the main menu as the rootViewController of your main window, and then present the login view controller on top of it (using `presentModalViewController:`).

Create a delegate protocol in your login view controller, and make the main menu the delegate. WHen they login, the delegate method fires, and the main menu dismisses the login view. When they log out, the main menu can present the login view again.